# office script - range find - return row or array to power automate

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have been trying several different ways to write an office script to search for a value in a cell and return the row or rows to power automate.

I believe I need to use **range.find** in order to make use of the "**completematch: true**" option.
However, I have also tried a **filter** and a **foreach** loop to find rows which **include** the text I am searching for.

I'm after a hint as to which method might be best?

essentially trying to:-

- power automate - pass text parameter to the script
- Scripts search for a match in excel business spreadsheet
- the script finds match(s)
- Script passes back the row(s) to powerautomate as an array

this is what I have so far: essentially it just finds the row number in which the matching result is found. This seems to work better to avoid partial matched (as happened with the  filter method )

any pointers, most welcome

```
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, siteNameToFilter: string) {
  let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let range = activeSheet.getUsedRange();

  let values = range.getValues();

  /**
  * This script searches for the next instance of the text "Fino" on the current worksheet.
 
  */
 
    // Get the next cell that contains "Fino".
    let findCell = range.find("Fino", {
      completeMatch: true, /* Don't match if the cell text only contains "fino" as part of another string. */
      matchCase: false,
      searchDirection: ExcelScript.SearchDirection.forward /* Start at the beginning of the range and go to later columns and rows. */
    });

    // Set focus on the found cell.
   findCell.select();

    // Remove the "TK" text value from the cell, as well as any formatting that may have been added.
    //tkCell.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
   
  let row = findCell.getRow().getUsedRange();
  let ur = findCell.getUsedRange();
  console.log(row);
  }
```

Comment: Are you running into an issue with your current process? Does the process not work as expected? Does it work but Is it running slowly? etc. Or are you just wondering if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: my current process only returns 1 resutl not an array of results (fine when there is no duplicates) I was wondering what the best way to achieve this is as there appears to be many ways to achieve this (yet none I can get working)

Answer (score 1):

I think Find may only be returning the first match. It sounds like you want all matches with the siteName. To do this, you'd either want to filter the range or loop through it.

Here's an example that loops through the range and adds the values from the rows containing the site name to an array. After the loop's completed, the array containing the values is returning by the function:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, siteNameToFilter: string) {
      let activeSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    
      let range = activeSheet.getUsedRange()
    
      let values = range.getValues() as string[][];
      let rowCount = range.getRowCount()
      let colCount = range.getColumnCount()
      let colIndex = range.getColumnIndex()
    
      let rowsArr: string[][][] = []
    
      for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
          if (values[i][j] === siteNameToFilter) {
            rowsArr.push(activeSheet.getRangeByIndexes(i, colIndex, 1, colCount).getValues() as string[][])
          }
        }
      }
    
      return rowsArr
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a deeper look as the above generates an error "[16, 86] Invoking read methods inside of a loop could lead to slow performance of the script. For more information, please visit https://aka.ms/office-scripts-performance". I had tried the filter previously but again struggled with returning an array rather than the first filtered row